# Flask server giving ImmutableMultiDict([])

Tags: react-native, flask, expo

I'm uploading multiple images using `expo-image-picker` but receiving `ImmutableMultiDict([])` on flask endpoint.

Here is the client code

```
  const addPhoto = async () => {
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [1, 1],
      quality: 1,
      allowsMultipleSelection: true,
      orderedSelection: true,
    })

    if (!result.canceled) {
      setImages(result.assets)
    }
  }
  const onUpload = async () => {
    const data = new FormData()

    const imagePromises = images.map(async (image, index) => {
      const response = await fetch(image.uri)
      const blob = await response.blob()
      data.append(`image${index}`, blob, `image${index}.${blob?.type?.split('/')?.[1]}`)
    })
    await Promise.all(imagePromises)

    await fetch(serverUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    })
  }
```

Flask endpoint

```
@app.route("/upload_image", methods=["POST"])
def upload_image():
    req = request.files
    print(req) //ImmutableMultiDict([])
    return Response("dummy response", status=200)
```

I logged the formdata it's adding images properly not sure what's happening in between.

PS: My goal is to upload the images in s3. From client it's working using `aws-sdk` but need to upload from backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved a while back forgot to post. Used file uri instead of blob.

```
 const addPhoto = async () => {
   const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
     mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
     allowsEditing: true,
     aspect: [1, 1],
     quality: 1,
     allowsMultipleSelection: true,
     orderedSelection: true,
   })

   if (!result.canceled) {
     setImages(result.assets)
   }
 }
 const onUpload = async () => {

   const formData = new FormData()
   images.forEach((image) => {
     const uriParts = image.uri.split('.')
     const type = uriParts[uriParts.length - 1]
     formData.append('images', {
       uri: image.uri,
       type: `image/${type}`,
       name: `${uuid.v4()}.${type}`,
     } as unknown as Blob)
   })

   await fetch(serverUrl, {
     method: 'POST',
     body: formData,
     headers: {
       Accept: 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
     },
   })
 }
```

```
@app.route("/upload_image", methods=["POST"])
def upload_image():
    images = request.files.getlist("images")
    # process the images
    return Response("dummy response", status=200)
```

You can also pass base64 string in the server then decode the base64 and upload to s3, not sure how efficient it is but works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should loop it in the files:

```
req = request.files
for key in req:
    file = req[key]
```